# Dear ImGui text/window call once but last forever

Tags: imgui

I am trying to figure out if its possible to do the following

```cpp
// OpenGL/GLFW/ImGui setup early in code

// Somewhere between initialization and start of rendering
// This is where all my classes/objects get initialized and want to display some data for them
ImGui::Begin("My Window");
ImGui::Text("Hello World");
ImGui::End();

// Later in code
while (rendering)
{
  ImGui::NewFrame();
  // Somehow here the "Hello World" text and MyWindow gets rendered
  ImGui::EndFrame();
}
```